# Transform Fourier of paths in symplectic vector spaces

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra, almost-complex

In the proof of Lemma 4.4.4 in "J-holomorphic Curves and Symplectic Topology" by McDuff and Salamon, They state the two following claims:

Let $(V,\omega)$ be a symplectic vector space, and $J$ be an $\omega$-compatible a.c.s, and $L \subset V$ be a Lagrangian subspace, Then:

1. Every loop $\gamma:S^1 \rightarrow V$ can be written as a Fourier series:

$\ \ \ \begin{align}\gamma(\theta) =\sum_{k=−\infty}^{\infty}e^{k\theta J}v_k\end{align}$

2. Every path $\gamma:[0,\pi] \rightarrow V$ with endpoints in L can be written as a Fourier series with coefficients $u_k \in L$:

$\ \ \ \begin{align}\gamma(\theta) =\sum_{k=−\infty}^{\infty}e^{k\theta J}u_k\end{align}$

My two question regarding these claims are (and the first one bugs me more!):

1. In the second claim, why are the coefficients in $L$?
2. Can someone link any source on such Fourier series (in vector spaces, using a.c.s instead of $i$)?

Comment: I believe that (1) is a straight forward generalization of the fact that a function $f: S^1 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ has real Fourier coefficients if it satisfies that $f(x) = \bar f(-x)$ for all $x$, and such functions are in bijection with functions $f: [0, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ with real endpoints.

Comment: for (2), I couldn't find a link, but I realized that it doesn't matter if I use an a.c.s or $i$ since there's always just a basis where the a.c.s is precisely $i$, i.e., $V$ is always isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^n$.